# Asset manager for NodeJs that reads supplied min files

Tags: node.js, assets

I'm checking a lot of the asset management packages for Nodejs. However, I can't seem to find a manager, that reads the "min" version of a file. Example: If I define, lets say, '/js/jquery.js' in the config, but in the same folder the "jquery.min.js" exists. So it should just add that, instead of uglify/minify the uncompressed one.

Comment: what's the reason of having `jquery.js` ? if you aren't reading the source or something the `jquery.min.js` the minified  version is just the same one..

Comment: Are you trying to have it serve the uncompressed version in development and the compressed in production?  Which asset management packages have you looked at?

Comment: numbers1311407: Exactly. I have looked at: https://npmjs.org/package/asset, https://npmjs.org/package/asset-rack and https://npmjs.org/package/bundle-up, but I can't find any docs saying it reeds the minified version. The ASP.net bundle features does that.